# Nonuniform sampling points based on the first order derivative of signal amplitude

Tags: sampling, nonuniform, probability-distribution-function

**Problem:**

- I need to measure a experimental data set $y(x)$.
- However, the experiment is extremely time-consuming and I don't have the luxury to have linearly spaced sampling point $x$.
- I need the density of sample points to be proportional to the first order derivative of the data $y^{'}(x)$.

**Progress:**

- first measure $y(x)$ once with uniform x as a test run, then compute $y^{'}(x)$.
- Then fit $y^{'}(x)$ to $pdf(x,\alpha, \beta, ... )$.
- Then I use the parameters to calculate new data points with inverse CDF $X=icdf[linspace[pdf(min),pdf(max),N],\alpha, \beta, ...]$

The problem is, this method only apply to data sets that is distributed in common probability distribution functions.

**Is there any way to make this work with arbitrary data ?**

Thanks in advance !

Comment: "I don't have the luxury to have linearly spaced sampling point x."  Meaning you don't have storage space to *keep* that much data, or the actual measurement itself is expensive?

Answer (score 1):

A method that I use very often to approximate the CDF is based on the observation that given a set of $N$ samples, the CDF at the point x the fraction of the points that are smaller than $x$. So if have a vector of sorted samples $S$ you could approximate the CDF as $cdf(x) = i/N$ if $S_{i-1} < x < S_i$.

A simple way to plot the CDF would be

plot(sort(S), (1:N)/N)

Then you can approximate the derivative by a difference equation. You could use a binary search to find the region of the vector $S$ where $x$ lies, say $idx(S, x)$, then you could compute something like

$i_1 = idx(S, x - \Delta)$, $i_2 = idx(S, s + \Delta)$ and use $(N \cdot (S_{i_2+1} - S_{i_1})) / (i_2 - i_1 + 1)$.

A different way to choose the anchor points would be, let $i = idx(S, x)$ and compute $(N \cdot (S_{i+k} - S_{i-k})) / (2k+1)$

And you can fit use a polynomial fit if you need a better accuracy where the CDF derivatives varies rapidly.